# TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (2 given) error when appending array through iteration

Tags: python, arrays, cs50

i want my code to find the position of capital letters and add them to an array. After testing, i get the error: TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
also when testing with a input with a singular capital letter it works fine, however when they are multiple capital letters, the array will only contain the last position.

```
for i in range(0,length):
    letter = camel_case[i]

    for k in range(0,25):
        check = capitals[k]

        if  check == letter:
            position = i
            print(f"{position}")

            global caps

            caps = []
            
            caps.append(capital_quantity,i)
            capital_quantity = capital_quantity + 1


        else:
            pass
```

Comment: I think you are looking for insert functionality

Comment: What was your thought process when putting i into that .append function? What did you want it to do?

Comment: this is just a snippet of the code. the value for i, if it passes the if function, is a position in the variable camel_case of a capital letter, so i wanted to note down the position so i know where it is for future manipylation

Answer (score 4):

The error is self-explanatory. The `append` function only takes a single parameter but two were passed.

Replace the following line of code:

```
caps.append(capital_quantity,i)
```

with this:

```
caps.append(capital_quantity)
```

Comment: i want to note down the position of the capital letter in the array, and there may be multiple, so should it be i instead of capital_quantity?

Comment: since you are concerned with finding the position of the capital letter, you can simply append the position of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

For lists, you can only append one item at a time. If you would like to keep capital_quantity and i together you could append them to your list as a secondary list i.e.

```
caps.append([capital_quantity,i])
```

Its worth noting, if for whatever reason you want to add both values to your list in a flat structure rather than a nested list you could use the.extend() method. [This](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/extend) is a good tutorial to understand the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you got `list.append` and `list.insert` mixed up.

`list.append` takes in one argument to add to the end of the list, whereas `list.insert` takes both a positional argument and the item to insert in that position of the list.

Additionally, there appears to be other bugs/fixes in your code.

1. `range(0,25)` should be `range(0,26)` since the last item in the range will be one less than the end argument (numbers 0-24 instead of 0-25)
2. `caps=[]` sets the list `caps` to an empty list every time it's called. I don't think that's what you want.
3. You don't need the `else:pass`
4. You don't need the `capital_quantity`. Just use `list.append`. If you need to count how many capitals are in the list, just do `len(caps)`

Here's how I'd implement this problem the most straightforward way:

```py
caps=[]
for i,c in enumerate(camel_case):
    if c.isupper():
        caps.append(i)
```

We check if each character `c` in the string `camel_case` is uppercase, and if it is, we append its index `i` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can save two or more data in a list with curly braces like this.

```
caps.append({capital_quantity,i})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list.extend method

`caps.extend([capital_quantity,i])` or

`caps.extend((capital_quantity,i))`